# "variable" target name in makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

how good/bad practice is it to have "nonconstant" targets in a makefile?

The company I work for produces embedded equipment, and I'm a firmware engineer.

The coding rules of the company I work for require that files produced by a build must have a name tagged with the version and also with a hash of information from a git repository (for test and production department needs).
An additional constraint is that a build is produced with a single command.

That's why I'm faced with makefiles every day whose targets have names that can change from build to build.

I wonder if these are common problems or not.
I wonder if the example I wrote is a good practice to solve it:

```
# This is just an example to (hopefully) help to understand. 

define populate_variable_with_remote_file_content
    $(if $(findstring $(origin $(1)),undefined), \
        $(eval $(1) = $(shell git archive master --remote=git@gitserver:project.git $(2) | tar -x --to-stdout)) \
    )
endef

.PHONY: clean populate_TAG

all: populate_TAG
    $(eval TARGET = dummy_$(TAG))
    $(eval export TAG TARGET)
    $(MAKE) -f $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST)) $(TARGET)

$(TARGET):
    echo hallo > $@

populate_TAG:
    $(eval $(call populate_variable_with_remote_file_content,TAG,somefile))

clean:
    rm dummy_*
```

I wonder if there are other (better) ways to solve this.

Comment: Variable targets aren't necessarily bad practices, but I'd consider changing variables inside recipes to be bad practice. Is there any particular reason to do that inside a recipe?

Comment: @root we don't want `make` to access the git server with every invocation. We want this to happen only if necessary. For example, the `clean` target (and other targets I didn't mention in the example) doesn't need access to git. This is related to the company's security policies towards consultants.

Comment: No worries if the names are predictable — same build should always produce the same output. I have worked on systems where the output filenames had _random_ GUIDs inserted. This was a scripting nightmare — smelly, hard to get right, and definitely not robust.

Comment: Remember the build can always produce two identical files, `latest_build.elf` and `A02-debug-2GiB-R2-a97f01a54b.elf` say. Just be careful you clean up properly if the build fdails.

Comment: @bobbogo thankfully no random in the name of the targets. Our names contain a fixed root, a version tag, the commig tag `git` (with `git describe`) and for some binaries a hash (of stuff contained in a `git` repository). But I can guarantee that the name uniquely identifies the build.